# MongoDB: count the number of items in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have a collection where every document in the collection has an array named `foo` that contains a set of embedded documents. Is there currently a trivial way in the MongoDB shell to count how many instances are within `foo`? something like:

`db.mycollection.foos.count()` or `db.mycollection.foos.size()`?

Each document in the array needs to have a unique `foo_id` and I want to do a quick count to make sure that the right amount of elements are inside of an array for a random document in the collection.

Answer (score 103):

In MongoDB 2.6, the Aggregation Framework has a new array [`$size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size) operator you can use:

```
> db.mycollection.insert({'foo':[1,2,3,4]})
> db.mycollection.insert({'foo':[5,6,7]})

> db.mycollection.aggregate([{$project: { count: { $size:"$foo" }}}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5314b5c360477752b449eedf"), "count" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5314b5c860477752b449eee0"), "count" : 3 }
```

Comment: Are there any way that we can get 7 (4+3) in this case?

Comment: @xxbidiao Sure, just use a `$group` stage which sums up the array sizes: `db.mycollection.aggregate({$group: { _id: null, totalSize: { $sum: { $size: "$foo"}} }})`.

Comment: I had to put `[ ]` around `{$project: { count: { $size:"$foo" }}}` for it to work, see https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1519#issuecomment-441348191

Comment: @Max Either syntax should work in the `mongo` shell (I just tested in the 4.2 shell), so your bug appears specific to Robo3T. However, passing the aggregation pipeline as an array in the shell [`aggregate()` helper](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) is the preferred approach in modern versions of MongoDB so you can include additional options as a second parameter. Note that the original answer is from 2014 and there have been many changes in MongoDB since then ;-).

Comment: @Max I'd also suggest looking for a more actively updated tool than Robo3T. Each Robo3T release embeds a specific version of the `mongo` shell which may cause unexpected issues when used with mismatched MongoDB server release versions (for example, significantly older or newer). Most admin tools use the MongoDB API for broader cross-version compatibility. [MongoDB Compass](http://mongodb.com/compass) is free and supported by the MongoDB team, but there are many alternatives depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for those infos ;)

Comment: if there are undefined arrays.then it will be counted as 0 doing this -> db.collection.aggregate([{$project: { count: { $size: { "$ifNull": [ "$foo", [] ] } } } }])

Comment: but i need to `find` first, before getting sizes, how should it be?

Comment: @datdinhquoc You can add an initial [`$match` stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to your aggregation pipeline to filter documents before applying the projection. Without any other stages, this aggregation query would process all documents in the collection. Modern versions of MongoDB (3.4+) also have an [`$addFields` stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) which can be useful to create output including existing fields from the input documents as well as newly added fields like a count of array items.

Comment: tks, using `$match` now

Answer (score 33):

if you are on a recent version of mongo (2.2 and later) you can use the aggregation framework.

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: '$foo'},
  {$group: {_id: '$_id', 'sum': { $sum: 1}}},
  {$group: {_id: null, total_sum: {'$sum': '$sum'}}}
])
```

which will give you the total `foo`s of your collection.

Omitting the last `group` will aggregate results per record.

Comment: Awesome, helped me as well. Can you suggest how can I have an access to "total_sum" in further calculations?

Answer (score 5):

Using Projections and Groups

```
db.mycollection.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
                _id:0,
                foo_count:{$size:"$foo"},
            }
        }, 
        {
            $group: {
                foo_total:{$sum:"$foo_count"},
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Multiple child array counts can also be calculated this way

```
db.mycollection.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
                _id:0,
                foo1_count:{$size:"$foo1"},
                foo2_count:{$size:"$foo2"},
            }
        }, 
        {
            $group: {
                foo1_total:{$sum:"$foo1_count"},
                foo2_total:{$sum:"$foo2_count"},
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Comment: anyway to protect if the array is missing in a document?

Comment: @chovy I know you probably no longer need this, but you can add `foo1:{$type:"array"}` in the `$match` stage.