# how to iterate over a cursor in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, iteration

My current assignment asks

```
The queries listed below must be implemented by iterations over a cursor.
```

Im confused on what iterations over a cursor means? Ive tried researching on my own to understand this concept but im still a bit lost of the idea.

The first question is

```
 List the title and total number of keywords for each book. If a book has no
keywords, the total number of keywords must be 0 (zero).
```

Here is the relevent JS script

```
db.bookshop.insert( {
    "_id":"185.3.16",
    "book": {
        "callnum":"185.3.16",
        "isbn":"1-292-06118-9",
        "title":"Database Systems",
        "authors":[
            {
                "fname":"Thomas",
                "lname":"Connolly"},
            { 
                "fname":"Carolyn",
                "lname":"Begg"}
        ],
        "publisher":"Pearson Pty Ltd",
        "year":2015,
        "price":136.99,
        "topic":"Computer Science",
        "description":"This is the 6th edition. You can register online to access the examples",
        "keywords":["Database", "XML", "Distributed"]
        }
});

db.bookshop.insert( {
    "_id":"163.24.12",
    "book": {
        "callnum":"163.24.12",
        "isbn":"1-123-456-810",
        "title":"Core Java",
        "authors":[
            {
                "fname":"Horstmann",
                "lname":"Cornell"}
        ],
        "publisher":"PH Pty Ltd",
        "year":2012,
        "price":142.90,
        "topic":"Computer Science",
        "description":"It covers JAVA programming and JAVA script",
        "keywords":["JAVA", "XML", "Script"]
    }
});

db.bookshop.insert( {
    "_id":"123.45.67",
    "book": {
        "callnum":"123.45.67",
        "isbn":"1-123-456-789",
        "title":"Algorithms",
        "authors":[
            {
                "fname":"James",
                "lname":"Bond"},
            {
                "fname":"Harry",
                "lname":"Potter"},
            {
                "fname":"William",
                "lname":"Stallings"}
        ],
        "publisher":"Pearson Pty Ltd",
        "year":2013,
        "price":65.85,
        "topic":"Computer Science",
        "description":"It contains algorithms and their applications. You can download examples from the website"
    }
});
db.bookshop.insert( {
    "_id":"134.41.33",
    "book": {
        "callnum":"134.41.33",
        "isbn":"1-213-431-770",
        "title":"C++ Programming",
        "authors":[
            {
                "fname":"Larry",
                "lname":"Peterson"}
        ],
        "publisher":"Pearson Pty Ltd",
        "year":2010,
        "price":74.90,
        "topic":"Computer Science",
        "description":"C++ programming and its applications",
        "keywords":["C++", "Class", "Overloading", "Inheritance"]
    }
})
```

this is my attempt

```
var myCursor = db.bookshop.aggregate([]).pretty();

while (myCursor.hasNext()) {
   var x = myCursor.next();
   if(x.book)
   print(tojson(x));
};

while (myCursor.hasNext()) {
   var x = myCursor.next();
   if(x.journal)
   print(tojson(x));
};

while (myCursor.hasNext()) {
   var x = myCursor.next();
   if(x.musicCD)
   print(tojson(x));
};

while (myCursor.hasNext()) {
   var x = myCursor.next();
   if(x.magazine)
   print(tojson(x));
};
```

this attempt prints but does not count.

If someone could possible explain the concept through the question ive provided that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387969/mongodb-count-the-number-of-items-in-an-array) help,
you should use aggregate, then count.

Answer (score 0):

**what iterations over a cursor means?**

lets first see **what is cursor?**

In simple words, a **cursor** is a result after the query is run.

So the data/result returned after the query is executed is a cursor.

[read more about cursor](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/mongodb/cursor-in-mongodb/)

From the question description provided by you, this is my understanding:

*You have to form a query to accomplish your tasks and iterate over the result of the query to output the results.*

The script provided by you is to insert those data into DB, and then perform your operations/tasks on this inserted data.

**What will be the query?**

I will leave those to you,

try it...

If you need help,

update your question with code samples that you have tried...

**AFTER COMMENTS:**

Here is the **solution**:

```
db.bookshop.aggregate({$match:{}},
    {$project:{"book.title":1, keywords: {$ifNull: ["$book.keywords", []]}}},
    {$project:{"book.title":1, noOfKeywords:{$size:"$keywords"}}})
```

I used **`$ifNull`** **operator**, to check if keywords array exists in book object in each document,

in this line

```
{$ifNull: ["$book.keywords", []]}
```

if the **keywords array is null or does not exists** then it will replace that particular document's keyword field with `[]` in book object.

Then in the next **`$project` stage**, I used **`$size`** operator to count the size of the array and that is your answer.

Comment: hey dude ive updated my question with an attempt. I just need help with the count. @niranjan harpale