# mongodb: how to get the length of array with http method?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

insert many:

```json
[
  { comments: [{foo:1}, {foo:1}, {foo:1}, {foo:1}] }
  { comments: [{foo:1}, {foo:1}] }
  { comments: [{foo:1}, {foo:1}, {foo:1}, {foo:1}, {foo:1}] }
  { title: 'foo' }
  { comments: [{foo:1}, {foo:1}, {foo:1}, {foo:1}, {foo:1}, {foo:1}] }
]
```

I am trying to find a method to obtain the length of something from [the document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/).

I would like to know how to obtain the desired result:

```json
[{count: 4}, {count: 2}, {count: 5}, {title: 'foo', count: 0}, {count: 6}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB: count the number of items in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387969/mongodb-count-the-number-of-items-in-an-array)

Comment: @ray I tried the method provided in your answer, but encountered an error message that reads, "The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: missing." I'm not sure how to verify whether the array exists.

Comment: Can you post your current attempt?

Comment: @ray https://mongoplayground.net/p/KOAmdltnlh3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the case of missing field by wrapping it with `$ifNull`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "count": {
        "$size": {
          $ifNull: [
            "$comments",
            []
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LHJA4vDbJL8)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with this issue.